# Spherical distance between two points on Earth

Tags: search, geometry, shortest-path, haversine

I am trying to find distance between two points on Earth. But all I know is their latitude and longitude range(Both points lie in that range) and the x and y coordinates on the USA map. I am using data from this website
http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml

I looked at some formulas for calculating the spherical distance but they seem to use the latitude and longitude for each point. How can I get the latitude and longitude for each point from this data?

Comment: what do you mean by x-y coordinates? those on a Mercator projection, or world coordinates

Comment: I am not sure. Can you take a look at that website and see which are those?

Comment: I wish they were lat/long coords. But they say its X-Y coords. http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/format.shtml#coord

Comment: oops sry my bad. IHDK, but the phrase _"X-Y coordinates in the plane associated with nodes of the graph"_ seems like a world-to-2D projection of some sort (Mercator probs). would you like answers to both cases? you could then perhaps try both and see which one works

Comment: Yeah. I would like answers to both cases. Thanks.

Comment: oops again: I totally forgot that you need the Z component as well; and to constrain your coordinate plane to a spherical surface would require a curvilinear coordinate system (like the Mercator uses) anyway... (~_~) I'll just do that then...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a Mercator projection, convert X-Y to lat-long.

---

*X to longitude:*

[image]

Important to realize that the projected length of C, C', is the same regardless of latitude (theta), with the equator having the *same* length C = C', *but* also with the exception of the poles, which are coordinate singularities. (Essentially the long-winded way to explain a spherical-to-cylindrical projection). Therefore we use linear interpolation.

[image]

---

*Y to latitude:*

[image]
[image]

Note that the formula does not work directly for negative Y-coordinates; instead compute the latitude for *positive Y* and take the *negative* of that.

(And ignore the x in the above two diagrams; they're y's O_o)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I do not understand this, so I will trust you and use this :)

Comment: @s_123 hope it works out. and oh yeah the angles are in radians, so you'll need to convert to degrees. and you have the formula to calculate distance from lat-long angles?

Comment: I think I would use Haversine formula. Do you of any other formula that's easier/more efficient in terms of computing?

Comment: @s_123 ah nice I haven't heard of this method before. I was thinking of a sort of vector-based formula but apparently everyone uses Haversine (¬_¬) so much for my own rambling

Comment: @s_123 update: oops I misinterpreted the definition of Mercator's cylindrical projection; rederived the formula for you

Comment: No problem. Thanks :)